# In my asp.net mvc 2 application, why are parameters passed via RedirectToAction sometimes lost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, redirecttoaction

In my asp.net mvc 2 application, why are parameters passed via RedirectToAction sometimes lost?

This perplexes me. Sometimes using RedirectToAction works, sometimes it doesn't. I haven't found any rhyme or reason to it. Here's an example:

```
        return RedirectToAction("ExportReport",
            new { FieldOrder = fieldOrder });
```

I've also tried this variant:

```
        return RedirectToAction("ExportReport", "SearchAndExport",
            new { FieldOrder = fieldOrder });
```

I added the following in my global.asax.cs:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "ExportReport",
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{FieldOrder}",
            new { controller = "SearchAndExport", action = "ExportReport", FieldOrder = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

And lastly, the prototype for the action I'm redirecting to:

```
public FileContentResult ExportReport(List<String> FieldOrder)
```

FieldOrder's data never makes it to the redirected action. Why? I know I've done this and had it work many times as well. What gives?

**EDIT 1**

To make it perfectly clear, FieldOrder is a `List<String>`. I am not using site areas. The redirect itself works, but the data is not passed to the method. I have verified that there is data that should be passed via debug.

Also, I'd rather not use TempData. If you have more than one action redirect to another more general action, that becomes messy. It's cleaner (IMHO) to just pass the data via the parameter.

Comment: are you using areas? Does the redirect always work correctly?

Comment: I am not using any areas. The redirect does work correctly aside from  not passing the value I put in the return RedirectToAction line as the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over some of my old questions here...

The reason these redirect values were getting lost was that I was passing a complex object as a parameter. ASP.NET MVC 2 did not handle these. Redirects with primitive type parameters will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Store your `FieldOrder` in TempData (holds the data for only one redirect) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx

Comment: I know that's a viable option, but I hate doing that. Its easy to get lost in the mix. Using RedirectToAction in the manner I've described should work. I want to know why it's not. Thank you for your suggestion, though.